# Convert array of objects with mismatched properties to csv

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

In short, how to convert this

```
$al = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$al+=[PSCustomObject]@{prop1="value1"; prop2="value2"}
$al+=[PSCustomObject]@{prop1="value11"; prop3="value33"}
$al+=[PSCustomObject]@{prop4="value444"}
```

Into this

[image]

Comment: See related issue request: [Add -UnifyProperties parameter to Select-Object `#13906`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13906)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `psobject` hidden memberset to discover all the property names before exporting:

```
$propertyNames = $al |ForEach-Object {
  # Discover all the object's properties
  $_.psobject.Properties |ForEach-Object {
    # Get each property name
    $_.Name
  }
} |Sort-Object -Unique

# Now the CSV will have a column for every single unique property name
$al |Select-Object $propertyNames |Export-Csv -Path $Path1 -NoTypeInformation
```